# Two problems I can't solve when parsing the text how do i parse to the other way from right to left too?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the class that do the parsing:

```
public static string[] ParseText(string text, int startPos, int endPos)
{
            List<string> parsedText = new List<string>();
            string[] entries = null;

            if (startPos >= 0 && endPos > startPos)
            {
                string images = text.Substring(startPos + 1, endPos - startPos - 1);
                entries = images.Split(new[] { ',' });
                for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    entries[i] = entries[i].Replace("\"", "");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    parsedText.Add(entries[i]);
                }
            }
            return entries;
}
```

And in `Form1`:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (mouseisup == false)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionToSearch;
                    textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1);
                    previousChar = positionToSearch;
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    mouseisup = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    if (currentChar > previousChar + 1)//currentChar < previousChar - 1)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentChar;
                        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentChar, 1);
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    mouseisup = false;
                } 
            }
}

private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                mouseisup = true;
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        string[] text = Parse_Text.ParseText(richTextBox1.Text, positionToSearch, currentChar);
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = text[i];
        }
    }
```

What it does now if I have a text in the richTextBox1 for example:

```
Daniel is greater > the the smaller < then >> higher is < Daniel
```

So if I click first time on the first D then I click on the second D

The text in richTextBox2 will be:

```
aniel is greater > the the smaller < then >> higher is <
```

If I click on `i` and then on `>`

So the text in richTextBox2 will be now:

```
s greater
```

Until this point everything is working good.

The problem is when I click backward for example I click on the last D of Daniel
And then i click on D of the first Daniel.

Then im getting exception in the new class since :

```
if (startPos >= 0 && endPos > startPos)
```

And then thevariable entries is null.

How do i handle this case when i try to parse backward ? In Form1 i tried some thing but i check if textBox2 is empty and set the bool to true something here stuck me.

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                mouseisup = true;
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Since textBox2 is empty it will be always true.
But i need to check if text is null the variable text is null then do something:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            string[] text = Parse_Text.ParseText(richTextBox1.Text, positionToSearch, currentChar);
```

If i check here if text is null and then textBox2 is empty then it will be true all the time the bool variable.

Second problem is if I want to allow the user to parse from right to left ?

If I mark the first D and the last D its ok.

But if first i click on the last D and then the first D its returning null.

So the two problems:

1. How to handle the null entries variable if the code is as it is now? If it is null I want that the user will be start over again.
2. If i want to change the code and allowed to parse from right to left ? What should I change in the new class code ?

EDIT**

```
public static string[] ParseText(string text, int startPos, int endPos)
        {
            List<string> parsedText = new List<string>();
            string[] entries = null;
            int tempPos = 0;
            if (startPos > endPos)
            {
                tempPos = startPos;
                startPos = endPos;
                endPos = tempPos;
            }

            if (startPos >= 0 && endPos > startPos)
            {
                string images = text.Substring(startPos + 1, endPos - startPos - 1);
                entries = images.Split(new[] { ',' });
                for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    entries[i] = entries[i].Replace("\"", "");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
                {
                    parsedText.Add(entries[i]);
                }
            }
            return entries;
        }
```

This is the button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            string[] text = Parse_Text.ParseText(richTextBox1.Text, positionToSearch, currentChar);
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                richTextBox2.Text = text[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: In `button1_Click` some code is missing.

Comment: In button click i should check for text if its null ? Tried but what to do if its null ? I want that if its null it will be like a reset so if i click on a char to the left it will add it to textBox1 and will start all over again. But since i keep clicking on the left to the left its null all the time. And since textBox2 is empty then the bool mouseisup will be true .

Comment: Current code will not compile because the variable `i` is missing in `button1_Click`. Also, last line of code is nested in braces, but is not in any kind of if-for-while-using-try statement, which is suspicious. Like some code is missing.

Comment: Dialecticus for some reason it didnt copy the complete button click event code. Im updating it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to 2 is pretty simple, if the startPos is greater than the endPos then swap them

```
if(startPos > endPos)
{
    tempPos = startPos;
    startPos = endPos;
    endPos = tempPos;
}
```

Also do you realise in your button click you're only ever showing the last element in your parsed text. If you want to show them all on separate lines you could change it like follows

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    string[] text = Parse_Text.ParseText(richTextBox1.Text, positionToSearch, currentChar);
    richTextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, text);
}
```

Comment: Kev i updated my question with your answer what i did i guess its wrong. Can you show me how ot do it ?